# Binding Microsoft.Web.DynamicData assembly at runtime failing

Tags: asp.net, dll, dynamic-data, dllregistration

I've got a project using DynamicData that was wrote by somebody else. Every time i try debbuging it, I get the message I've attached at the bottom

I've already tried deploying the DynamicData dll to GAC, and throwing it into the bin folder, chceking the assemblies full names, installing again VS SP1, and .NET Framework SP1, and chceking the logs in Fuslogvw.

I've run out of ideas at this point. Could anybody help me, or at least suggest a new direction of searching for the solution ? Thx in advance.

The error message I get :

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = DOMAIN\user
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Web.DynamicData
 (Partial)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/AppBase/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:/AppBase/bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:/AppBase/bin/web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event to learn more about the Assembly that's being requested. You can check that the version numbers and everything else match. If you have the dependency already loaded, then you can just return it from the event handler. I've included some sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460271/how-to-use-assembly-binding-redirection-to-ignore-revision-and-build-numbers/2344624#2344624).