# Redirecting DLLs with different public key token

Tags: .net, dll, publickeytoken

In my project, I have Assembly A built on PKT(public key token) X.

One of the other project, same Assemly A is built on a different PKT Y. Both the assemblies are present on same machine.

I want to have only one version of Assemly A to be used across all projects. For this, the project using Assembly A with PKT Y should be forced to use the one with PKT X.

I tried to look into Publisher policy but it is not doable.

Any suggestions on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still waiting for an answer but based on the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191296/net-assembly-binding-redirect-with-differing-public-key-tokens?rq=1), it looks like it isn't possible.

Comment: It isn't possible and it will never be due to the Strong Name mechanism (cybersecurity)