# The type 'HttpResponseMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am just trying to build my application without visual studio by using MSBuild.

Using

- Visual Studio Build Tools 2017.
- Dot Net framework 4.6.1 SDK
- MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664'

Full Error Message :

> error CS0012: The type 'HttpResponseMessage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Any idea why? Thanks...

**Update**

This is the dll path with visual studio

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Http.dll

This is without visual studio, only with MSBuild

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Plugins\CredentialProvider.Microsoft

File path is different. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Loran, any update about this issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, Your answer makes me some point and I found version different and reference location is different. So I just make it to reference to the same location and build again. now It works. But I still need to check. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: Besides, you can strongly set the `hintpath` of the `System.Net.Http.dll` to a specific path. And use that to make sure that they use the same path or similar path. Also, thanks for sharing your solution and glad to know the issue went away. I have added your solution into my answer and some details.  You can check it. See my `update 1` :) And if it helps, you could consider `accept it`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your project has used a newer version dll about `System.Net.Http` and if some dependencies use the old version `4.0.0.0 System.Net.Http.dll`, it will miss the old one.

**Besides**, please the following steps:

**1)** make sure that your `xxx.csproj` file has this node, if not, you should modify like this:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

**Also**, try to set **Copy Local** of `System.Net.Http.dll` to `true`.

Modify such node like this in `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
     <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
```

**2)** open CMD as **Administrator** and then type:

```
     cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools
               
     gacutil /i xxxxx\System.Net.Http.dll(path where the System.Net.Http.dll exists)

 // like the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Http.dll
```

**3)** Maybe you could try this in `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <dependentAssembly>  
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http"  
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
                              culture="neutral" />  
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0"  
                             newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>  
         </dependentAssembly>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

There is [a similar issue about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe/62770487#62770487).

**4)** then delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then use **Build Tool for VS2017** to build the project again.

=====================================================

**Update 1**

Thanks for sharing your solution. Actually, Not sure that whether system cannot find the `System.Net.Http` when you move your project into Build agent.

Actually, you can use hintpath to force the path to reference `System.Net.Http` in your project and make sure that they are the same. Also, this solution will make sure the dll will copied into output folder. And it will make VS or msbuild find and identify the DLL.

**And you have changed the location of the DLLL to the same so that the issue is fixed.**

You can try to use this in your `xxx.csproj` file:

It will also copy such dll into output folder.

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

or

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
          <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config or App.config add:

```
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
             <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
             </assemblies>
          </compilation>
```

Comment: @D A, Still having the issue.