# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe Version=4.0.6.0

Tags: c#, redis, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am working with a ASPX App in .NET... I new is this APP, it was assigned to me to do a simple modification..

When I try to run it its gave the error ...

```
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.6.0,
```

i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe) article.. It has the best explanation and how to solve it...

As it says, I have to update my app.config like this

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

But it was already done..

I read that Nuget Version and assembly version is like this

```
4.7.0 is 4.0.6.0
4.7.1 is 4.0.6.1
```

My package.config says

```
<package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Following the explanation... `4.7.1` refers to `4.0.6.1`  and I have `4.0.6.0` in my app.config....

Should I replace the package to `4.7.0` ?

If I already have `4.0.6.0`. in me config, Why is the error says it does not find `4.0.6.0.` ?

The latest version in Nuget is `v.6.0.0`

It is better to update Nuget Package?

Thanks

Comment: you got any lead?