# How can get System.Runtime dll to deploy when i Publish from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a project that i am publishing using visual studio. The project includes a reference to System.Runtime.dll located in

```
Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades
```

But when i Publish , for some reason that dll is not deployed .

Does anyone have any ideas on this ?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Is it showing .dll not found?

Comment: the log has the following error:    Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.6.0,

Comment: Ok, did you check this link which has a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe