# Azure SQL Managed Instance Connection with .net 4.8 api/svc host

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, .net-4.8, azure-sql-managed-instance

We have a .net 4.8 application with api and svc host projects where our applications are hosted in Azure Virtual Machine (IIS), and our Databases are hosted in SQL Managed instance. They are in the same vnet in different subnet.

Managed identity of VM is created in managed instance.

Before, the application was in a vm and on prem sql server was being used.

Connection strings

```
<add name="AppContext" connectionString="Server=***; Database=App_DevDB; Trusted_Connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="BackgroundJobsContext" connectionString="Server=***; Database=Hangfire_DevDB;Trusted_Connection=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

We are trying to figure out the changes to have our app connect with the DB in managed instance (db context, conn string, etc.) but not able to get any related information per our requirement. Also we do not want to use user id/pwd in our connection string.

It will be great to get some directions from the community to help figure this and learn about it.

Please let me know if I can provide any more details.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-sql check this Document if it helps you?

Comment: @PratikLad Thank you so much. I am going over this however there have been some package mismatch which I am looking into. Will update soon as I can if this works out.

Comment: @PratikLad it somehow seems connected, so when I added the package and the code as per the link my test is failing with System.***O.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'? I have binding redirect for 0.0.0.0 to 6.0.0.0 to 6.0.0.0. I tried to have it to 4.0.4.1 as well but get the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62770487 check this solution for similar issue.

Comment: I have been through this thread, even my project has 6.0.0.0 nuget package so I updated my web config binding redirection with all permutation combination but did not work. I also saw this nuget package which is used by some other packages and some of them are present in my solution but not sure how to get into this rabbit hole

Comment: Reinstall the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe starting with all dependant packages.