# Strong named assembly alongside unsigned assembly

Tags: c#, twilio, .net-assembly, docusignapi

I have a situation where Docusign API is referencing the RestSharp signed assembly with a public key token of 598062e77f915f75. In the same project I am using the Twilio API which also references the unsigned Restsharp assembly, obviously with a null public key token.

I can make one or the other work but not both at the same time since I can't add both the signed and unsigned RestSharp references since they both have the same name.

When I have a reference to the signed assembly, the Docusign part works but the Twilio code errors with this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

When I reference the unsigned assembly, Docusign errors with this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=100.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Is there any way around this?

I have tried binding redirects in every combination I can think of:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-100.0.0.0" newVersion="105.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="598062e77f915f75" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-100.0.0.0" newVersion="105.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Have you tried using bindingRedirect?

Comment: I have both directions. Added to original question.

Comment: With different publicKeyToken the assemblyRedirect configuration is a bit more complicated. Try use the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158928/referencing-2-different-versions-of-log4net-in-the-same-solution/3163050#3163050

Comment: Complain to twilio...

Answer (score 0):

I can think of few possible ways to solve this issue:

1. **Binding redirect**. Works if assemblies have same public key, otherwise you need to specify code base. See SO answer: [Referencing 2 different versions of log4net in the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158928/referencing-2-different-versions-of-log4net-in-the-same-solution/3163050#3163050)
2. Using **GAC**. Not sure if it would work with unsigned assembly.
3. Making use of **AppDomain.AssemblyResolve** event (see [How to use Assembly Binding Redirection to ignore revision and build numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460271/how-to-use-assembly-binding-redirection-to-ignore-revision-and-build-numbers/2344624#2344624))
4. **Signing / unsigning** assembly with one key using **`ildasm`**.

I once had similar issue with different log4net versions being referenced by our project and 3rd party library. Here is a [blog post](http://andriybuday.com/2010/10/log4net-versions-deployment-issue.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I have used the Nuget package of RestSharpSigned. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to redirect every version up to the current to the latest installed version:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="RestSharp" publicKeyToken="598062e77f915f75" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-105.2.3.0" newVersion="105.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```